# how to troubeshoot an Access Sub problem

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-access

This one has me stumped.  We have an Access 2003 database that has been in use for roughly 2+ years (database is on a network share).   The database has several forms with print preview and print command done via onClick Sub's.

Machines in the office, Vista/Access 2007, Vista/Access 2003, XP/Access 2003, etc. Can all print preview no problem to all of the forms.  However, I have one particular machine, a Vista mchine that has Access 2007.  - some print or print-preview commands work great, with the excepton of one in particular.

It doesn't seem to be a Vista or a 2007 issue, but within this machine itself.  And where the database is off of a share - I'm doubting it is that either.

Anyone have any ideas on where to look now?

Comment: Are you talking about printing a report or printing the form? If the latter, you are ignoring this principle: FORMS are for printing, FORMS are for displayin/editing data. I wouldn't waste any time trying to troubleshoot printing forms at all.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think I have to - suspend - this.  Went back to the machine, and for the first time in about a year - it printed just fine.

my guess is that opening it with a xp / 2003 combination - somehow re-converted it into a 2003 database format.

just a guess though.  be happy if anyone had any theories incase this happens again.